# Add RecyclerView to Tabs Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

i have a simple fragment with 2 tabs and i want to add a recyclerview in each fragment. my question is how can i attach the recyclerview to each fragment ?
this is my MainAdapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private List<ListMenu> menuList = new ArrayList<>();
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
  @Override        
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("SINGLE"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("PACKET"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final Pageradapter adapter = new Pageradapter(
                     getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(
                    new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
      }        
      @Override
      public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
      @Override
      public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to take the recyclerview in each fragment layout. And in the fragment classes you have to set adapter for corresponding recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

You must using FragmentPagerAdapter or PagerAdapter with Fragment

You can see example :

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Hope! Help you

Comment: i already made the fragment pager, what i want is to add a recyclerview list in the fragmentpager

Comment: in layout of fragment. you can add recyclerview

Comment: And you use YourAdapter in YourFragment